# How to pass a Parse File to a new View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller

I am attempting to pass a PFile containing an image to a new image view controller however I can't seem to successfully pass the file.

Here is the code where I attempt to pass the file in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

PurchaseItemViewController*purchaseItemViewController = [[PurchaseItemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

purchaseItemViewController.objectID = _objectIDArray[row];
purchaseItemViewController.imageData = _bookImageData[row];
purchaseItemViewController.authorOfBook = _authorNameArray[row];
purchaseItemViewController.titleOfBook = _bookNameArray[row];

purchaseItemViewController.bookCoverImageView.file =_bookImageData[row];

NSLog(@"HERE IS THE DATA %@",_bookImageData[row]);
NSLog(@"here is the file %@",purchaseItemViewController.bookCoverImageView.file);

[purchaseItemViewController.bookCoverImageView loadInBackground];
 // purchaseItemViewController 
// Push the view controller.
[self presentViewController:purchaseItemViewController animated:NO completion:Nil];
```

}

When I execute the code I get the following log out

016-02-09 14:36:33.265 ParseStarterProject[17786:7270793] HERE IS THE DATA "PFFile: 0x7fbe12f7dcb0"

2016-02-09 14:36:33.266 ParseStarterProject[17786:7270793] here is the file (null)

can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the view controller is not ready for its views to be configured (e.g. `bookCoverImageView`) at the time this code is running.

The proper ordering of steps is to build the `purchaseItemViewController` as you do, set the properties from your data source, then present it.  Don't try to configure its views or load the image.

```
PurchaseItemViewController*purchaseItemViewController = [[PurchaseItemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

purchaseItemViewController.objectID = _objectIDArray[row];
purchaseItemViewController.imageData = _bookImageData[row];
purchaseItemViewController.authorOfBook = _authorNameArray[row];
purchaseItemViewController.titleOfBook = _bookNameArray[row];

// TOO EARLY FOR THIS:  
// purchaseItemViewController.bookCoverImageView.file =_bookImageData[row];

NSLog(@"HERE IS THE DATA %@",_bookImageData[row]);
// TOO EARLY FOR THIS:
// NSLog(@"here is the file %@",purchaseItemViewController.bookCoverImageView.file);

//  TOO EARLY FOR THIS:
// [purchaseItemViewController.bookCoverImageView loadInBackground];
[self presentViewController:purchaseItemViewController animated:NO completion:Nil];
```

The first chance you have to configure views will be in `PurchaseItemViewController`, in `viewDidLoad`.  There, you'll be able to say...

```
PFFile *file = self.imageData;  // this is a PFFile with a confusing name
self.bookCoverImageView.file = file;
[self.bookCoverImageView loadInBackground];
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Happy to help.  Incidentally, I meant to mention on the other question, it might be better if, instead of an array for each attribute of the fetched objects, why not just keep one array of PFObjects returned by the query?  Then you can get at all the attributes at once.

Comment: that is a very intelligent suggestion I will attempt to implement it.

Comment: :-)  And then same for the new view controller in this question.  You can pass just one PFObject instead of 4 or 5 of its attributes.